# How to increase the efficiency for saving multiple rows in .NET windows application?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, windows

In my .NET Windows application, I need to insert around 10 millions data per time.However, it takes more than 5 minuites to save into SQL server according to my inefficient code.Are there any best way minimize the time taken to save those data?

```
private void saveAllDataInGrid()
    {
        int rowCount = dataGridView1.RowCount;

        String str = "server=DESKTOP-TDV8JQ7;database=ExcelFileApp;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
        for (int count = 0; count < rowCount; count++)
        {
            try
            {
                String query = "insert into TemMainTable values (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15,@p16,@p17,@p18,@p19,@p20,@p21,@p22,@p23)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[9].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[10].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[10].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[12].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[13].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[14].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p16", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[15].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p17", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[16].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p18", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[17].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p19", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[18].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p20", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[19].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p21", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[20].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p22", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[21].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p23", dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[22].Value.ToString());

                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                lblDataSaved.Text = "No of rows Saved : " + rowCount;
            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved");
    }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: 1. Do this in a transaction, 2. use stored procedure, 3. parallelize code

Comment: Look at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Comment: It looks like you're transferring a datagridview into a sql server database. Where does the data on the datagridview come from? You can't tell me someone has typed 1 million rows of data into a datagridview.

Comment: The .NET most efficient way of inserting many rows into a SQL Server table is using SqlBulkCopy class. If the data comes from an Excel file you can get a datareader from it and call SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer

Answer (score 5):

You can use `User-Defined Table Types` for bulk insert. You need to create a `User-Defined Table Types` in the database `SQL Server Management Studio >> Programability >> User-Defined Table Types`

The SQL Script Syntax will be like this to create the `User-Defined Table Types`

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableList] AS TABLE(
    [SampleColumn1] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SampleColumn2] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL    
)
```

The Sample SQL Insert Query will be as below -

```
INSERT  INTO SampleTable
        ( SampleColumn1 ,
          SampleColumn2

        )
        SELECT  cusTbl.SampleColumn1 ,
                cusTbl.SampleColumn2
        FROM    @TableList AS cusTbl;
```

In C# Code - the general Syntax to insert is as below -

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);    
var tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableList", tableList);
tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvparam.TypeName = "dbo.TableList" 
cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Note:** You had used `DataGridView` in your Windows Application. So you can easily pass the `DataTable` which you had used to bind the `DataGridView`.
Take care that the `DataTable` have same `ColumnName` and `DataType` which is declared in SQL Server Database `User-Defined Table Types`

**I need to insert around 10 millions data per time.However, it takes more than 5 minutes**
Definitely time taken to insert will reduce - compared to sending rows one by one to SQL Server.
[More Reading Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=performance%20benefit%20for%20%60User-Defined%20Table%20Types%60&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) and in [this Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/09/23/maximizing-throughput-with-tvp/)